# Groovy @TypeChecked Error

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I'm using the Spock Framework to write unit tests and have encountered the following error when adding @TypeChecked to my test classes:

```
Error:(16, 9) Groovyc: [Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method org.spockframework.runtime.SpockRuntime#verifyMethodCondition(org.spockframework.runtime.ErrorCollector, org.spockframework.runtime.ValueRecorder, java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, <unknown parameter type>, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[], java.lang.Object, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Integer). Please check if the declared type is right and if the method exists.
```

Here's the Maven dependency I'm adding:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-groovy-2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Here's the dummy unit under test:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    public class TypeCheckedIssue {
        public List<String> getList() {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("hello");
            list.add("goodbye");
            return list;
        }
    }
```

Here's the Spock test in Groovy:

```
import groovy.transform.TypeChecked
import spock.lang.Specification

@TypeChecked
class TypeCheckedIssueTest extends Specification {
    def "determine if exists in collection"() {
        given:
        TypeCheckedIssue typeCheckedIssue = new TypeCheckedIssue()

        when:
        List<String> result = typeCheckedIssue.getList()

        then:
        result.contains("hello")
    }
}
```

Can anyone interpret the error and/or point to a possible issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need your test TypeChecked? I would suggest typechecking the code under test rather than the test itself. Spock is very dynamic and uses a lot of ASTs under the hood... not sure it's really compatible with TypeChecked.